# Value not returning due to double if while statement

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This code applies to ACF where I try to make 2 shortcodes coming from the same group of data. Below does only return `city` into a value, and not `address_line`. I gotta feeling this might to do that with the identical if : while statements. However, they are in 2 different functions, I'm not sure why this doesn't work. (I tried hard to find a similar questions to this, but no luck, probably because I do not understand the problem).

```
function city(){
    if( have_rows('address') ) :
        while( have_rows('address') ):
            the_row();
            $city = get_sub_field('city');
            if ( get_post_type() == 'listings' ) {
                return $city;
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;
}
add_shortcode('city','city');
    
function address_line(){
    if( have_rows('address') ) :
        while( have_rows('address') ):
            the_row();
            $address_line = get_sub_field('address_1');
            if ( get_post_type() == 'listings' ) {
                return $address_line;
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;
}
add_shortcode('address_line','address_line');
```

Comment: That is a very odd style of code, and very hard to read. I thought it was a [do-while loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) in disguise, but thinking about it more, the if is just completely redundant. But I can't see anything obvious that would actually stop it working, and you haven't mentioned any errors, so I can only assume the problem is somewhere else that we can't see. Maybe there just isn't any data for 'address_1'?

Comment: why not return array and one single function : `function address_line(){
    if( have_rows('address') ) : while( have_rows('address') ): the_row();
    $city = get_sub_field('city');
    $address_line = get_sub_field('address_1');
    if ( get_post_type() == 'listings' ) {
        return [$address_line,$city];
    }
    endwhile;
    endif;
}
add_shortcode('address_line','address_line');`

Comment: @user2864740 He added the `advanced-custom-fields` tag, that's ACF.

Comment: @AlivetoDie okay, but your shortcode would run the values together, I need 2 separated values.

Comment: @IMSoP good comment; however I have tested that, and they work separately from each other, just not together in this particular case.